# What's the definition of F[x] and F[[x]], where F is a field?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, field-theory

> What's the definition of F[x] and F[[x]], where F is a field?

I know this might be a stupid question but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere.

Comment: 1) the ring of polynomials in $X$ with coefficients in $F$;  2) the ring of formal power series with coefficients in $F$, that is, all formal sums $a_0+a_1X+a_2X^2+\cdots$, with the natural addition and multiplication.

Comment: I am afraid the question is about how these rings are defined... There might be answers for this on MO and m.se. This should be helpful for the polynomial ring: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Polynomial_ring

Comment: Are you asking how they are defined formally, or are you trying to remember what the symbols mean?

Comment: See for example, this question, which came up recently, for how they are formally defined. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1434397/how-to-define-indeterminates-formally/1434415#1434415

Answer (score 1):

$$
F[x]=\left\{\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i\colon a_i\in F,n\in\{0,1,\cdots\}\right\}
$$

$$
F[[x]]=\left\{\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_ix^i\colon a_i\in F\right\}
$$

Comment: -1 for dropping quantifiers and using imprecise and confusing notation.

Answer (score 1):

$F[x]$ represents the ring of polynomials over the field F. Formally, this ring can be defined as the set of functions with finite support (taking only finitely many nonzero values) from the natural numbers into the field. The operations are defined as follows:

$$
    (f+g)(i):= f(i) + g(i)  \text{       }\forall f,g \in F[x] \text{ and } i \in \mathbb{N} \\
    (fg)(i):= \sum_{j=0}^{i}f(j)g(i-j)  \text{       }\forall f,g \in F[x] \text{ and } i \in \mathbb{N}
$$

The product defined above is often called Cauchy product.

At this point, you might think that this construction has little to do with the usual polynomials we know from highschool. However, notice first that a function $f$ from $\mathbb{N}$ can be represented as a sequence or infinite tuple as follows:

$$
f=(f(0),f(1),f(2),...)
$$

Now, if you define $X^{i}:=(0,0,...,1 (\text{ith-spot}),0,0,0...)$ (i.e. the function sending i to 1 and everything else to zero), you will realize that we have just defined usual polynomials. Checking this might be a good exercise. Prove, for instance, that $XX=X^{2}$. The operations defined above turn quite nicely in just the usual way in which we add an multiply polynomials. For example, the finite support restriction takes care of the fact that polynomials have only finitely many terms.

The ring $F[[X]]$ is called the ring of formal power series over $F$. The definition is identical to the one described above, except for a very important detail: we do not require the functions in $F[[X]]$ to have finite support. Thus, we get a ring whose elements look the way we would expect:

$$
a_{0} + a_{1}X + \dots + a_{n}X^{n} + \dots \text{ with } a_{i} \in F
$$

where we have defined $X$ exactly as above.

Comment: I've always thought of this as obtuse as a definition but fine as an exercise.